# Pandas adding sum of columns in pivot table (multiindexed)

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have df and df_pivot with below code:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo",
                         "bar", "bar", "bar", "bar"],
                  "B": ["one", "one", "one", "two", "two",
                         "one", "one", "two", "two"],
                  "Year": [2019, 2019, 2019, 2019,
                         2019, 2019, 2020, 2020,
                          2020],
                  "Month": ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "01", "02", "03"],
                  "Values": [2, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 8, 9, 9]})


df_pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, values='Values', index=['A', 'B'],
                    columns=['Year','Month'], aggfunc=np.sum, fill_value=0)
```

df_pivot looks like below:

```
Year    2019                2020      
Month     01 02 03 04 05 06   01 02 03
A   B                                 
bar one    0  0  0  0  0  6    8  0  0
    two    0  0  0  0  0  0    0  9  9
foo one    2  4  5  0  0  0    0  0  0
    two    0  0  0  5  6  0    0  0  0
```

now what I am trying to do is to add basically three columns into this df:
2019FY, 2019YTD, 2020YTD

2019FY column should be sum of all values under "2019"

2019YTD column should be sum of all values under "2019" where period is defined, i.e. if period is defined as 04, 2019YTD should sum columns under 2019 for 01/02/03/04

2020YTD column should be sum of all values under "2020",

Output table should look as below:

```
Year    2019               2019FY 2019YTD 2020      2020YTD
Month     01 02 03 04 05 06                01 02 03
A   B                                 
bar one    0  0  0  0  0  6  6      0      8  0  0      8
    two    0  0  0  0  0  0  0      0      0  9  9      18
foo one    2  4  5  0  0  0 11      11     0  0  0      0
    two    0  0  0  5  6  0 11      5      0  0  0      0
```

Essentially I would like to know how I can sum column with given "Month", as from here I can create 2019FY/2019YTD/2020YTD on my own, also it is important to add them in specific slot in the pivot table (at the end of 2019 data and at the end of 2020 data).

Is it feasible?

I was looking everywhere but could not find example how to do it.

Appreciate the help

Thanks
Pawel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each year is possible create new columns in custom function, so in ouput is also `2020FY` columns in [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
def f(x):
    #get all months and convert to integers numbers
    c = x.columns.get_level_values(1).astype(int)
    #sum all values
    s1 = x.sum(axis=1)
    #sum 1,2,3,4 months
    s2 = x.loc[:, c <= 4].sum(axis=1)
    x[(f'{x.name}FY','')] = s1
    x[(f'{x.name}YTD','')] = s2

    return x

df = df_pivot.groupby(level=0, axis=1, group_keys=False).apply(f)
print (df)
Year    2019                2019FY 2019YTD 2020       2020FY 2020YTD
Month     01 02 03 04 05 06                  01 02 03               
A   B                                                               
bar one    0  0  0  0  0  6      6       0    8  0  0      8       8
    two    0  0  0  0  0  0      0       0    0  9  9     18      18
foo one    2  4  5  0  0  0     11      11    0  0  0      0       0
    two    0  0  0  5  6  0     11       5    0  0  0      0       0
```

If need remove columns use `tuple`s, because `MultiIndex`:

```
df = df.drop([('2020FY','')], axis=1)
print (df)
Year    2019                2019FY 2019YTD 2020       2020YTD
Month     01 02 03 04 05 06                  01 02 03        
A   B                                                        
bar one    0  0  0  0  0  6      6       0    8  0  0       8
    two    0  0  0  0  0  0      0       0    0  9  9      18
foo one    2  4  5  0  0  0     11      11    0  0  0       0
    two    0  0  0  5  6  0     11       5    0  0  0       0
```

Comment: Dear jezrael,
I have tried to run your code, but I do not receive same result after print(df) I receive my own df with no additional columns for FY/YTD,  can you please advise?

Thanks
Pawel

Comment: @PawełPoprawski - So it means there is month not more like `4` ? Because `s1` is for summ all rows per years, `s2` is fr sum first 4 columns only.

Comment: I have used my initial df, where I assume I should receive same result as you.
Did you change any formating for months in my original df table?

Comment: @PawełPoprawski - No, but I use pandas `1.2.3`, yuor version is different?

Comment: I updated my pandas and now it works.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the:

```
df.columns.get_level_values()
df.index.get_level_values()
```

syntax to slice multi-indexed rows and columns. I'd suggest changing your df's month column from string "01", to integer values, which makes it easier to slice using < > operators.
If however, you need to stick with string valued month column names, then:

```
month_num = 4
df_pivot["2029YTD"] = df_pivot.loc[:, (df_pivot.columns.get_level_values(0) == 2019) & 
                                   (df_pivot.columns.get_level_values(1).astype(int) <= 4)].sum(axis=1)
df_pivot["2019FY"] = df_pivot.loc[:, df_pivot.columns.get_level_values(0) == 2019].sum(axis=1)
df_pivot["2020YTD"] = df_pivot.loc[:, df_pivot.columns.get_level_values(0) == 2020].sum(axis=1)
```

You'd end up with something like:

```
    Year    2019    2020    2019YTD          2019FY 2020YTD
Month   01  02  03  04  05  06  01  02  03          
A   B                                               
bar one 0   0   0   0   0   6   8   0   0   0   6   8
    two 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   9   9   0   0   18
foo one 2   4   5   0   0   0   0   0   0   11  11  0
    two 0   0   0   5   6   0   0   0   0   5   11  0
```

Once that's done, you can then adjust the column positions by using something like:

```
df_pivot = df_pivot.loc[:, [2019, "2019FY", "2019YTD", 2020, "2020YTD"]]
```

To get something like:

```
    Year    2019         2019FY  2019YTD 2020      2020YTD
Month   01  02  03  04  05  06          01  02  03  
A   B                                               
bar one 0   0   0   0   0   6   6   0   8   0   0   8
    two 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   9   9   18
foo one 2   4   5   0   0   0   11  11  0   0   0   0
    two 0   0   0   5   6   0   11  5   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: OP need `also it is important to add them in specific slot in the pivot table (at the end of 2019 data and at the end of 2020 data).`

Comment: Heya, formatting column positions after you've ran the above code should be an easy task with the same logic using something like: `df_pivot.loc[:, [2019, "2019FY", "2019YTD", 2020, "2020YTD"]]` and you'd get your expected results :)

Comment: Yep, I have it running side by side at the moment and I don't see any issues

Comment: ok, thanks. Only problem is there is years from 1990 to 2020, then is a bit problem use your solution. Because it is a bit `'manually'`, not dynamic

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo",
                         "bar", "bar", "bar", "bar"],
                   "B": ["one", "one", "one", "two", "two",
                         "one", "one", "two", "two"],
                   "Year": [2019, 2019, 2019, 2019,
                            2019, 2019, 2020, 2020,
                            2020],
                   "Month": ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "01", "02", "03"],
                   "Values": [2, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 8, 9, 9]})

print(df)

df_pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, values='Values', index=['A', 'B'],
                          columns=['Year', 'Month'], aggfunc=np.sum, fill_value=0)
print(df_pivot)

# create the same pivot, but just using the year total
df_year_pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, values='Values', index=['A', 'B'],
                               columns=['Year'], aggfunc=np.sum, fill_value=0)
print(df_year_pivot)
# since the dataframe you wish to add will have 2 index levels
# you need to add another level when you join the resulting data
# and since your new level will be a YTD, I just appended it to the year
multi_index_tuples = [(x, f'{x}YTD') for x in df_year_pivot.columns]

# now, you are going to add the new index level to the df with the level names the same as your first pivot
df_year_pivot.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(multi_index_tuples, names=['Year', 'Month'])

# happily join on the same index
total_df = pd.merge(df_pivot, df_year_pivot, how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True)
print(total_df)

# sort the column index
total_df = total_df.sort_index(axis=1, level=[0,1])
print(total_df)
```